# How to make a window span across multiple screens in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

I would like to create a window, say chromium-browser to be displayed in full screen across multiple screens.

I can manually drag / resize it to span across all the screens, but when I try to initiate or resize a window programmatically and set its size to be larger than the screen it always snaps back to the size of a single screen.

chromium-browser --window-size=3000,1080

all the screens are 1920x1080, I would expect this command to set the window to overflow to the next screen, instead it resizes it's width to 1920 automatically.

disable snapping

chromium-browser --window-size=3000,1080 would set the window width to 3000 and not snap back to the width of a single display.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and SuperUser cover more general questions.

Comment: Any update on this?